# Mixing small and big data models in 16-bit DOS & Watcom

Tags: ms-dos, programming

I want to write an application for DOS using small code/data model, but I would like to use far pointers for some selected memory blocks. I would like to use the OpenWatcom C++/16 compiler.

So, for most of the things I would like to have near pointers, but one array in the program I'd like to store using a far pointer, because it's big, accessed rarely, and I don't want to pollute my near heap with this large blob.

Normally I'm allocating the memory using `malloc()`, and this produces normal near pointers to my data from the "near" heap. For the larger array, I'd like to use `_fmalloc()` to allocate the data from the "far" heap.

*Question number 1*: Is it possible to mix `malloc()` and `_fmalloc()` in the same program using small memory data model?

I'm having doubts if that's possible, because the Watcom docs have this comment in [clib.pdf](http://sininenankka.dy.fi/%7Esami/watcom_mirror/clib.pdf):

> The _nheapgrow function attempts to grow the near heap to the maximum size of 64K. You will want to do this in the small data models if you are using both malloc and _fmalloc or halloc. Once a call to _fmalloc or halloc has been made, you may not be able to allocate any memory with malloc unless space has been reserved for the near heap using either malloc, sbrk or _nheapgrow.

So I happily call `_nheapgrow()` on the beginning of my program:

```
int main() {
    _nheapgrow();
    uint8_t far* ptr = (uint8_t*) _fmalloc(20);
    printf("ptr: %08lX\n", ptr);
    ptr[0] = 0;  
    return 0;
}
```

The problem is that the call to `_fmalloc()` now returns a memory location which seems to overlap with other allocated memory blocks in the near heap (and the application data). In this example, it overwrites the "NULL pointer protection area", a 0x20-sized memory block filled with 0x01's which is supposed to guard against null pointer dereferences. This is reported as:

[image]

*Question number 2*: is this normal behavior, or is it a bug in the stdlib?

When switching to large data memory model, everything seems to be fine, since "near" heap isn't used at all (I think). Everything is aliased to `_fmalloc()`, `_ffree()`, etc, and the "near" variants are never called.

So in order to use `_fmalloc()`, am I forced to switch to large data memory model?

Comment: You cast to `(uint8_t*)` and not to `(uint8_t far*)`.

Comment: I think I'm sitting on this for too long. You're right, it's that easy.

Comment: It's easy to make that kind of mistake. I suggest liberal use of `typedef` to _name_ types and give you a bit more protection - not protection form the compiler - that won't help with a cast - but protection when you're writing/reading your code.

Comment: How large is your far data going to be? If it can be bigger than 64KB, you need a huge pointer to iterate through it.

Comment: @JohnDallman: Huge pointers have such a huge amount of performance overhead that they should be avoided whenever possible.  Normal practice on real-mode 8086 is to ensure that no *individual* object exceeds 65,520 bytes, but use separately indexed objects which, in aggregate, would not be subject to any such limitation.

Comment: Also, write `uint8_t *x;`, not `uint8_t* x;`. I know C++ programmers like to delude themselves into thinking the declarator grammar is something else that it actually is, but you have no reason to repeat the same mistake in C.

Comment: If the missing keyword was the only issue causing the bug when mixing allocations in different models, could you please write a little explanation as an answer? @antekone I'm an OW user, but I've never mixed models before. If its as simple as 'yes it works straightforwardly under the conditions in the docs' it'd be a useful conclusion for me :)

Comment: knol, I can write the answer, although I think it's @user3840170 who should write one, and I would accept it as an answer. If not, then I'll do what you suggest in a couple of days. But generally yes, everything works when following the docs. Also, mixing memory models was more of a "because I want to do it this way" thing, not really because of any necessity.

Comment: Thing is, this is exactly the kind of question that would have been closed as ‘caused by a typo’ on Stack Overflow, and I don’t see how asking it here makes it any more worthy of an answer post instead of closure.

Comment: @user3840170 The answer to 'how do I mix X and Y data models? are there any caveats?' isn't just 'I made a typo [closed, deleted, bye]', it's 'You can mix data models X and Y provided you always use the correct type of pointer type to store the pointer. The example in the question omits a cast. The correct approach is XYZ, ensuring to store/use the pointers like XYZ'. That's what makes it a helpful answer. Just because the approach attempted in the question was wrong, doesn't invalidate the task itself. That it would be closed on SO (if it would be) is an SO problem.

Comment: @knol The answer to ‘I know how this thing is supposed to work, but my seemingly reasonable code still fails to do what I intended, did I miss anything?’ is indeed ‘you just made a typo, and since there is a practically inexhaustible number of ways one can make a silly error such as this and ask about it, where the symptoms are ever so different and the answer only useful to the single person asking, there is no point in keeping such questions for future readers of this ostensibly long-term knowledge base’.

Comment: @user3840170 We may have to agree to disagree on this, but I suggest you focus your  attention on the 'question number 1/2' phrasing present in the question and you'll see where I'm coming from.

Comment: @user3840170: I wouldn't describe the omission of a qualifier as a "typo", but rather a failure to account for the fact that code which casts e.g. a `long far *` to an `int*` will work correctly on the large memory model, but when using small memory model it will be treated as a cast to `int near*`.,

Comment: @supercat I would, because it’s clear to me (0) that the asker knows pretty well what near and far pointers are and how DOS memory models work, and (1) that the error merely escaped the asker’s notice, and once pointed out, it was acknowledged as trivial. Their response to my comment was ‘You're right, it's that easy’, and not ‘But should it even matter/aren’t these the same?’.

Comment: Oh, and by the way: this is yet another [reason not to cast the return value of memory allocation functions in C](https://stackoverflow.com/a/605858/3840170).

Comment: @user3840170: The removal of a *semantically required* memory space qualifier through type casting is a language-design defect which would manifest itself in many other situations that would be likely to bite people using compilers that use different memory spaces whether or not one were to cast the results of an allocation function.

Comment: @supercat Setting aside whether it’s good that casts can discard address space qualifiers without warning (I would argue it’s defensible: casting is an explicit request to override the type system, it better do what it says), why complain about it *to me*? I just mention common advice how to work with a language that exists instead of writing rants of no consequence about what it should have been.

Comment: I'm also pretty sure the compiler will have issued a warning on the "far" being casted away.

Comment: @user3840170: My intended point was that the question/answer could have value because some people might not realize that a cast without memory space qualifier would not support round-trip conversion.

Comment: @tofro: In an era where implicit pointer target-type conversions were allowed but deprecated, a common usage of casts was to avoid type conversion warnings.  Unless a compiler retained a distinction between `(int*)` and `(int near*)`, even in small model, until the pointer's target was evaluated, there would be no way for it to warn about accidental narrowing while still allowing programmers to avoid unnecessary diagnostics for deliberate narrowing.  And if a compiler is preserving such distinctions, retaining qualifiers would be both simple and useful.

Comment: @tofro: On a related note, if there were an explicit "integer to pointer" syntactic convention which was distinct from "cast something to pointer", e.g. `int *myPtr = (int*)(uint_ptr)(someIntegerExpression);`, then macros could much more safely incorporate pointer conversions on their arguments.

Comment: @tofro The Watcom compiler only warns for *implicit* pointer-narrowing conversions; casting suppresses the warning. I checked.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It was because of the wrong cast. The cast should be `(uint8_t far*)`, not `(uint8_t*)`.

Answer (score 2):

While it would have been sensible and useful to say that a pointer-to-pointer cast which specifies neither a `near` nor `far` qualifier would be interpreted as yielding a `far`-qualified pointer if the original is `far`, and a `near` qualified pointer if the original is `near`, that's not what x86 compilers from that era generally do (there may have be exceptions).  Instead, any pointer type which doesn't specify a qualifier will be interpreted as `near` when using the small or medium memory model, and as `far` when using the compact or large model.  Conversion of a `far` pointer into a `near` pointer will throw out addressing information which would be vital except in cases where the address in question identifies a "near" object; converting the pointer back to a `far` pointer will result in the generating code replacing that information with default value that would be correct for "near" objects, but erroneous for anything else.

Incidentally, while many people seem to view the notion of "memory models" as an 8086 quirk, the concept could be usefully employed even on many systems today.  For example, many small embedded programs on the ARM make heavy use of a few global objects, which would typically need to be accessed via pattern such as:

```
extern int x,y,z;
void test(void) { x = y + z; }

test:
  mar r0,__addresses12345
  ldm r0!,{r1,r2,r3}
  ldr r0,[r1]
  ldr r1,[r2]
  add r0,r0,r1
  str r0,[r3]
  bx  lr
  .align
__addresses12345:
  dw  y,z,x
```

The code above would take 28 bytes and 14 cycles, of which 18 bytes and 5 cycles would be used loading x, y, and z, while 10 bytes and 9 cycles would would perform actual work.  If there were a "tiny systems" ABI which specified that R7 would be left pointing to the start of a dedicated globals area, and the variables were declared as being within that area, then code size would shrink from 28 bytes to 10, and execution time would shrink from 14 cycles to 9.

IMHO, it would have been useful for the C Standard to have defined "near" and "far" qualifiers, leaving details of how--if at all--they map to system concepts as Implementation Defined, but having the general semantics that there is a certain amount of "near" address space (possibly all of it) which can be targeted by either "near" or "far" pointers, and that "far" pointers may be able to access storage that isn't accessible by unqualified pointers (if any such storage exists).  While the qualifiers may not have done anything useful on all systems, they could have been specified in a manner that would have made them harmless on systems where they weren't needed while making clear how they would need to be used to guarantee compatibility with systems that required them.

Comment: This is a bit like saying it’s reasonable to assume that an `(int)` cast actually casts to `long int` if the original type is `long` or `unsigned long`. Or that a `(char *)` cast actually casts to `const char *` if the original pointer is to a `const` type. Not to say this would have no advantages… but no other cast in C works that way, and it arguably would undermine the point of typecasting if it did. And I don’t suspect the asker had made any such assumption in the first place.

Comment: @user3840170: If C had included a "non-const" qualifier, then it would have been useful to say that qualifiers default to being retained when casting.  The reason casting has to default to removing qualifiers like `const` is that there's no other way for casting to remove them.  Further, conversions from `far` pointers to `near` pointers are so rarely semantically correct that among the possible treatments for `(int*)someFarPtr`, treating it as `(int near*)someFarPtr` is for most purposes less useful than would be treating it as a compilation error.